# I want convert json object into json array using js or groovy

Tags: javascript, json, groovy

sample input- '{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}'

expected output- ['{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}']

Comment: The way the output is described isn't clear to me.  It looks like you want an array with 1 element in it which is the string `'{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}'`, which is the same as your input string.  Can you elaborate on what it is that you want in the output array?

Comment: Perhaps JSON.parse / JSON.stringify will help you. Check this question out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object

Comment: I want when ever any json object will come it will convent into json array @JeffScottBrown

Comment: still question is unclear. your expected output is an array of string...

Comment: i want when ever we got json if it starts with "{" then wanted to push "[" and "]" at the start and end of json.

Answer (score 0):

> want when ever we got json if it starts with "{" then wanted to push
> "[" and "]" at the start and end of json.

If that is all you need then you could do this:

```
String input =  '{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}'

// ...

if(input.startsWith('{')) {
    input = "[${input}]"
}
```